# Left/right brackets spanning multiple lines within aligned environment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, braces

I'm trying to draw tall square brackets on both sides of a four-line component of an equation within an `aligned` environment. I've tried `\Bigg[` and `\Bigg]`, but these aren't tall enough for me. I also tried inserting invisible brackets with `\left.` and `\right.`, but those don't span all four lines. I also tried using `\vphantom` but that didn't help either (I am not too sure how to use it, as I didn't see any examples using that command that show what I want to do). I did see some examples for using `\cases` to produce a single (left or right) tall curly brace, but I want a square brace, and on both sides (and in the middle of an equation).

Here's my code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{align} 
\ln{Y_{ijt}} = & \enspace \beta_0 + \sum\limits_{k=A,B,C}  
    \begin{aligned}
         & \left[ \Sigma_r \beta_{1kr} \ln(q_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n) \right. \\
         & \left. + \Sigma_r \beta_{2kr} \ln(p_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n) \right. \\
         & \left. + \Sigma_r \gamma_{1kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-1}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n) \right. \\
         & \left. + \Sigma_r \gamma_{2kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-2}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n) \right] \\
    \end{aligned}
    \mathbbm{1}(i \in k) \\ 
 & + \theta_{ij} + \lambda_{t} + \epsilon_{ijt} \nonumber
\end{align}
```

So, what I'd like to see is those left and right square brackets within the `aligned` environment span the whole four lines within that `aligned` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a tough formula.

I'd use `split` rather than `align`, so the equation number is centered with respect to the whole thing and the last line will not appear as hanging from nowhere. I'd also not replace `\sum` with `\Sigma`. Using `\textstyle` makes the summation symbol smaller.

Instead of `\mathbbm{1}` (that uses bitmap fonts), I suggest using the STIX2 symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stix2bb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n}{<->stix2-mathbb}{}

\newcommand{\indic}{\text{\usefont{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n}1}}% indicator function

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ln Y_{ijt} = \beta_0 &+ \sum\limits_{k=A,B,C}  
    \left[
    \begin{aligned}
         & \textstyle \sum_r \beta_{1kr} \ln(q_{it}) \indic(B_n) \\
         & \textstyle \quad + \sum_r \beta_{2kr} \ln(p_{it}) \indic(B_n) \\
         & \textstyle \quad + \sum_r \gamma_{1kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-1}) \indic(B_n) \\
         & \textstyle \quad + \sum_r \gamma_{2kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-2}) \indic(B_n) \\
    \end{aligned}
    \right]
    \indic(i \in k) \\ 
 & + \theta_{ij} + \lambda_{t} + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I had tried `\split` in an earlier iteration but had not worked it all the way through. (Also, I have never really liked the look of the `mathbbm{1}` indicator symbol, but have not known what to replace it with.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you like to have:

[image]

(red lines shows text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:long}
\begin{aligned}
\ln{Y_{ijt}} 
& = \enspace \beta_0 \\
& + \sum\limits_{k=A,B,C}
    \left[  \begin{multlined}
         \Sigma_r \beta_{1kr} \ln(q_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)
            + \Sigma_r \beta_{2kr} \ln(p_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)\\
         + \Sigma_r \gamma_{1kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-1}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)    
            + \Sigma_r \gamma_{2kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-2}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)
            \end{multlined} \right]\cdot\mathbbm{1}(i \in k) \\
& + \theta_{ij} + \lambda_{t} + \epsilon_{ijt} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the `bmatrix*[l]` environment from `mathtools`, and the `\medop` command from `nccmath` to obtain medium-sized sum symbols inside the matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\newcommand{\msum}{\medop\sum\limits}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:long}
\begin{aligned}
\ln{Y_{ijt}}
= \enspace \beta_0
& + \sum\limits_{k=A,B,C}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
         \msum _r \beta_{1kr} \ln(q_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)
            + \msum_r \beta_{2kr} \ln(p_{it}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n) \bigstrut\\%[2ex]
\addlinespace[0.8ex]
         {}+ \msum_r \gamma_{1kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-1}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)
            + \msum_r \gamma_{2kr} \ln(Y_{ij,t-2}) \mathbbm{1}(B_n)
            \end{bmatrix*}\cdot\mathbbm{1}(i \in k) \\
& + \theta_{ij} + \lambda_{t} + \epsilon_{ijt}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]